# RotateY will NOT stop flickering

Tags: html, css, animation

There has got to be some kind of property affecting my code that I can't figure out because when I make a JSfiddle, everything is fine.

Problem:
I am trying to do a transformation about the Y axis for three divs that is triggered by the `:hover` psuedo-element.  For some reason the div will NOT stop flickering, and I've tried every trick in the book from the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` for the element that is flickering, to the `-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);` in the parent div.  NOTHING is working.

Any guidance would be appreciated as I feel like there is something weird going on with another one of the divs in my code that's affecting the badges and making them continue flickering.

My code can be found here:  http://bmgz.rtcgraphics.com/#4 and the badges can be found when you click on a person's face.

Here is a link to my JSfiddle which weirdly enough, works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/sYBYd/1/

Any and all help would be SO appreciated!  Thank you!!

Comment: Can you describe the flickering? I'm not seeing it (using Firefox 30.0), unless you mean the text move up a pixel right before the flip.

Comment: It's a flickering that only affects Webkit browsers, so Safari and Chrome.  Sorry, I should have clarified!  The graphics look fine in Mozilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed when you disable the `background-image` from `#our-team` and the `background-color` from `#ot-window` and then clearing `-webkit-backface-visibility` from `.ot-badge` will make them behave like your JSfiddle. So during the transition the two 2D surfaces conflict with one another and go crazy. I'm at the front! No I'm at the front!

So if you change these it should work:

```
.ot-badge { -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px); }
.ot-badge:hover { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(-1px); }
```

And be sure to **remove**:

```
.ot-badge { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: I could seriously kiss you right now.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!  I just made the edits you mentioned, and also removed the -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0); from .ot-badge and everything is gravy!